# Why is one of the GridViewDeleteEventArgs.Values missing?

Tags: sql, gridview

I have a `gridview` with a `sqldatasource` containing 7 values.  The `gridview datakeynames` is `equipment_ID`; the rest are regular fields.

I'm trying to use `e.values("BME_No")` within `gridview_rowdeleted`, but it's empty.  Meanwhile, `e.values("equipment_name")` is full and `e.values.count` shows `values` are 5.  `values` are supposed to be 6, excluding the `datakeyname equipment_ID`.

From the article here {no url supplied}, I see `datakeynames` are excluded from `values`.  On the other hand, `BME_No` is not a `datakeyname`.

How should I proceed?

**sqldatasource:**

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_GV" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MedicalEquipmentLibrary_DBConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="Select_Equipments" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" UpdateCommand="Update_Equipment"
        UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure" CancelSelectOnNullParameter="False" DeleteCommand="Delete_Equipment"
        DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearch" Name="BME_No" PropertyName="Text" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Equipment_ID" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Equipment_ID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="BME_No" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Equipment_Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Model_Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Vendor_Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Manufacture_Name" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**Gridview_rowdeleted event:**

```
 Protected Sub GV_Main_RowDeleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeletedEventArgs) Handles GV_Main.RowDeleted
        lblMessage.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        lblMessage.Visible = True
        lblMessage.Text = "Equipment " + e.Values("BME_No") + " is deleted."
    End Sub
```

Comment: You mention an "article here", but do not supply a URL or link.  Please supply the link.

Answer (score 0):

- If the field is a bound field, check that the column is visible.
- If it is a template field, check that the field is two-way bound. From the [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewdeletedeventargs.values(v=vs.110).aspx):

"The Values property is populated only when two-way binding expressions are used in the item template"